# Urban Airship crashing app

Tags: android, push, noclassdeffounderror, urbanairship.com

I'm having a problem when trying to integrate Urban Airship PUSH notifications in my android app.

I think that I've got all my permissions and intent filters in the AndroidManifest set, but the app crashes immediately after trying to set my AirshipConfigOptions like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
    ...
}
```

My error log says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using ProGuard? See [this article about configuring ProGuard to work with UrbanAirship](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/241918-deploying-your-android-app-with-proguard).

Are you using ADT r17 or later? Starting from r17, jar files need to be located in "libs" folder, placing them in "lib"  won't work (even though Eclipse indicates no problems). See [this article about dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).

Comment: How do I check which version I'm currently using? In the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: In Eclipse, Help > About Eclipse, click on the green Android icon ("The Android Open Source Project") or click on "Installation Details"

Comment: Thanks - yeah, it's showing r17 - do you know where the folder I should drop the ua lib file in is located?

Comment: In your project root, next to "src", "res", etc. create folder "libs" and place your jar files there. Then do "File / Refresh" and "Project / Clean..." in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, it's done. But now I get this error in the console:
nstallation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-04-17 15:59:25 - Life] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-04-17 15:59:25 - Life] Launch canceled!

Comment: Sorry, that was an unrelated error - everything's working now. Big thanks!